# Message property file issue in Spring + Thymeleaf + Tiles

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles, thymeleaf

The content of my message property file doesn't show up properly. What I get is ??key?? on a web page.

The following is a related section of my Spring web Java configuration:

```
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    resolver.setOrder(2);
    return resolver;
}

public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    engine.addDialect(new TilesDialect()); // Tiles
    engine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect()); // Tiles
    engine.addDialect(new ConditionalCommentsDialect()); // Tiles
    return engine;
}

   @Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

    ThymeleafViewResolver delegate = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    delegate.setViewClass(ThymeleafTilesView.class); // Tiles
    delegate.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    delegate.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    delegate.setOrder(1);
    delegate.setViewNames(new String[] { "*" });
    delegate.setCache(false); 
            return delegate;
}

@Bean
public ThymeleafTilesConfigurer thymeleafTilesConfigurer() {
    ThymeleafTilesConfigurer ttc = new ThymeleafTilesConfigurer();
    ttc.setDefinitions(new String[] { "/WEB-INF/defs/views.xml" });
    return ttc;
}

   @Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {

    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasenames("/WEB-INF/messages/messages");
    messageSource.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);
    messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");      
    messageSource.setCacheSeconds(0);
    return messageSource;
}
```

In a comparison of the configuration on this Thymeleaf tutorial (http://xpadro.blogspot.ca/2014/02/thymeleaf-integration-with-spring-part-1.html), the only difference is Tiles related configuration. What is wrong with the above configuration?

Comment: I can retrieve a message from Java code by the way. And I also try to set messageSource on SpringTemplateEngine.

Comment: I had this same issue. I found that I couldn't get ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource to work. I was able to get it to work with ResourceBundleMessageSource. I never figured out why exactly. The only thing that stands out is that the SpringTemplateEngine.setMessageSource take a parameter of final MessageSource which is probably why the Reloadable class isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I have tried to use ResourceBundleMessageSource before. To verify it, I try it again and don't have a luck. Other configuration element likely play a role.